"ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database" How to connect to the database from nestjs?
I'm tynna connect to the database "postgres" but it doesn't work.
Here is my configurations:
app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        port: parseInt(configService.get('DB_PORT')),
        entities: [],
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
        synchronize: true,
      }),
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

.env file:
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_PORT=5433
DB_NAME=postgres

docker-compose file:
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'root'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

Start command for container: docker-compose up
Start command for Nestjs: npm run start:dev
There is only 1 main module (app.module.ts)
The whole error:
[Nest] 24888  - 08.05.2024, 18:59:29   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
AggregateError:
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1683:7)

Trying add database to nestJS with official documentation of nestjs.

You've set DB_PORT=5433, but in your Compose file you're publishing the port (the first ports: number) on the standard PostgreSQL port 5432.

facepalm... God...
